# iOS Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CGFont'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2

When I Integrate the Uber SDK in to my project I have facing this error in swift 2.3 but I don't know to fix this.

```
class FontUtil {
static func loadFontWithName(name: String, familyName: String) -> Bool {
    if let path = NSBundle(forClass: FontUtil.self).pathForResource(name, ofType: "otf") {
        if let inData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
            var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
            let cfdata = CFDataCreate(nil, UnsafePointer<UInt8>(inData.bytes), inData.length)
            if let provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(cfdata) {
                if let font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider) ---> Error found in this line {
                    if (CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)) {
                        return true
                    }
                    print("Failed to load font with error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}}
```

Comment: The solution is given in the error message that you've put in your title. :) Hint: a thing that returned an Optional in a previous Swift version now does not return an Optional anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eric said, the `CGFontCreateWithDataProvider` function is no longer returning an `Optional` value, so you don't need to wrap this statement and the subsequent calls in the `if` optional binding. Your code will change to this:

```swift
let font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider)
if (CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)) {
  return true
}
print("Failed to load font with error: \(error)")
```